# Choosing between perl and python for my application

Tags: python, perl, language-choice

I am working for a small electronics company and I was assigned a task of re-inventing and re-writing the software for our product delivery flow, which gathers design components, verifies them, and creates a delivery tarball which later gets send to the client. I am debating whether to choose Perl or Python for this. I am considering pros and cons of both. I am not a software engineer by trade hence I wanted to ask you for advice.

Some background info:

The old flow is an ancient, long Perl script which runs all the sign-off checks the moment delivery is created, is ugly, has been patched a thousand times already, desperately needs to be replaced.

I plan to decentralize this such that each component is signed-off by an engineer responsible for the given component. The sign-off would amount to running a script which would kick-off a couple of EDA tools and parse their output to verify the status. Information about the status would be stored as a file containing some serialized data structure or an object.

The package-building script will only gather information about readiness of design components from the serialized files (is it signed-off? were the files modified since last sign-off? are there any waived errors?) and create a tarball.

I am considering the pros and cons of both solutions. I wanted to ask for some advice on this. Here are the things I have considered so far:

- I am familiar with both languages at the same level so no clear advantage here, except for Python being nicer to write in
- Almost all scripts in the company are written in Perl and this is the language that our engineers are familiar with. That said, we have almost no standardized libraries so there's not much that I could reuse anyway.
- Perl is a little bit outdated and has far less actively developed libraries compared to Python
- There is an interface allowing Perl to instantiate Python objects, however no easy way to go the other way around.
- Parsing text files (EDA tool logs) is easier with Perl
- Fresh engineers coming from the university are far more likely to know Python than Perl

I want to make an informed choice since this piece of software will certainly be used for years to come. I would appreciate it if you could give me some more arguments than those listed above that I could consider before I make a decision.

Comment: Python, despite your company has already Perl base. Some languages will extinct, and Perl has all signs of it, why to invest your time into it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Do you have some sources or metrics that I could look for that would be convincing? Two biggest arguments I see here is the existing code base (+ for Perl) and Perl becoming extinct (+ for Python). However I haven't found any satisfying metric to present the fact that Perl will become extinct.

Comment: Nothing ready to use, but you can google for such metrics like http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html (by pure luck Python is #1 and Perl is #20 and still declining). But it is more than that, I am dev for years and I simply observe -- how many books are released, how many jobs offers are out there, how the language itself is improved, etc etc. IMHO Perl was fine language for its time (first web apps, CGI scripts), then was deprecated by PHP, and while PHP still holds its niche, Python meanwhile simply exploded. I am not fan of it, I prefer languages with static typing, but for scripting, ML, and...

Comment: ...and many more Python is a king. For now. I simply wouldn't hesitate when choosing between de facto dead environment, and thriving one (currently), after all investing in the language is part of my life, and even "stupid" script can warm-up you for bigger scripts, even bigger ones, and so on. Btw. I don't mean literally "dead", I saw some job-ad about COBOL half-year ago, but it is a difference between ton of job positions and some sorry single one once a year.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perl is without doubt a terrible choice. Python is popular, but also old fashioned and unsupported. Personally I would recommend c#. However..

> Almost all scripts in the company are written in Perl and this is the
>   language that our engineers are familiar with

Really this is an overwhelming factor. Unless the company as a whole is moving away from perl to some chosen replacement, if individuals changing a bit of code here a bit of code there it's going to end up very messy.

It's better to decide on a single technology stack and stick to the options available within that space. You'll find things work together with less effort and less problems.

If you can, open up this discuss with the other engineers, see if there is a consensus on which way people want to go and see if you can get that made into an official policy.

If you can't make that happen, then just use the language which looks best on your CV